How to uninstall unwanted/extra npm packages
I had mysql installed through mySQL workbench, but i wasn't sure so i ran the command "npm install mysql" and it added 11 packages and audited 12. Now I don't want the extra added packages, but I am afraid that if I run the command "npm uninstall mysql", it can affect the packages I installed through mySQL workbench. Is there a way to fix this?
I was trying to install packages which I later realized I didn't need.

Mysql server and mysql workbench are two different applications. Mysql workbench does not install mysql server.

You can safely run npm uninstall mysql for the following reasons:

MySQL workbench does not use npm to install things; MySql was installed on your system without the use of npm.
npm packages are not typically installed globally, meaning that you install/delete them for specific projects without affecting the rest of your system.
The npm package you installed by running npm install mysql does not, in fact, include MySQL nor a server to run. It is only a driver that allows you to connect to an already running instance of MySql.

That said, given what you are describing above, I believe that you do intend to connect to MySql from your node application later on, in which case you would need the driver package, after all.

Thank you so much man. I appreciate this.
